# Python Xlsxwriter - Make dates respect different locale format

Tags: python, date, format, xlsxwriter

With Xlsx writer, I want to write dates that will respect the locale format set by the OS region/language settings. For example, the default format set by the OS in Canada is 'yyyy-mm-dd' while in Germany, it is 'dd.mm.yy'. How do I make the dates responsive?

I have read the documentation but still can't figure this out.

This is what I've tried:

```
import xlsxwriter
from datetime import date

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('sample.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

my_date = date(2020, 1, 31)
my_format = workbook.add_format({'num_format': 'mm/dd/yyyy'})
worksheet.write(0, 0, my_date, my_format)

workbook.close()
```

- In Excel set to English-Canada, I expect '2020-01-31' but get '01-31-2020'
- In Excel set to German, I expect '31.01.20' but get '01.31.2020'.

So it manages to use the proper delimiters but the rest is wrong.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I have a file which i have formatted the date using xlsxwriter in us date format (mm/dd/yy). When i open it with my computer the dates are appearing in european format (dd/mm/yy), while when i open it from my work's laptop they appear as us date format. So i presume that it has to do with the machine's locale settings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first question is whether it is possible to set a date format in Excel that will change to match the locale in the way that you want. I don't think it is.

If you set any "mm-dd-yyyy" style format in Excel then you will get that format in other locales (apart from the separator).

So if it isn't possible in Excel it won't be possible in XlsxWriter (and equally if it is possible in Excel then it will work the same in XlsxWriter).

One partial workaround is to use one of the [in-built Excel number formats](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/format.html#format-set-num-format) in XlsxWriter. These are number indexes and not strings:

```py
import xlsxwriter
from datetime import date

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('sample.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

my_date = date(2020, 1, 31)
my_format = workbook.add_format({'num_format': 14})
worksheet.write(0, 0, my_date, my_format)

workbook.close()
```

This date (31 December 2020) give `20-12-31` in the Canadian locale and `31.12.20` in the German locale. However, there isn't any built in format that give a 4 digit year.

See also [Number Format Categories](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/format.html#number-format-categories) and [Number Formats in different locales](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/format.html#number-formats-in-different-locales) in the XlsxWriter Docs.

Comment: So turns out that using {'num_format': 14} was the right solution. Now, Canadian locale shows 2020-01-31 and Germany shows 31.01.20. This is the same behavior as changing the format inside Excel. Thanks for your help.